# How to switch jobs between two already employed bitizens?

Tags: tiny-tower-vegas

I have two bitizens that are employed on different floors.  I'd like them to swap positions.  How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, but only with a 3rd job slot available.  There is no ability to swap jobs directly between bitizens but it is possible to take one bitizen and reassign it to another job (and paying the salary, of course).

To swap bitizen A who has job X with bitizen B who has job Y:

1. Move bitizen A from job X to job Z.
2. Move bitizen B from job Y to job X.
3. Move bitizen A from job Z to job Y.